# running programms on ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I am new on Ubuntu and I have a lot of software like itunes, canon image and printer software which have been installed under Microsoft. Do I have to reinstall them on Ubuntu? Or can I run them via Ubuntu? thank you in advance (even if it may seem like a naive question)
ronmylo

Comment: First, search native program that you want for Ubuntu. If you could not find, you can install Windows application via [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/)

Comment: Before trying to install Windows programs look for alternatives for Linux. See http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Alternatives

Answer (score 1):

You can't install Windows software on Ubuntu. You have to find alternatives.

Look [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsPrintersCanon) to see if your Canon printer is supported on Ubuntu.

Unfortunately there is no iTunes version or alternative for Linux so you will have to use wine emulator. Read [here](http://www.parityportal.com/2013/06/11/itunes-on-ubuntu-heres-how-you-get-it-running/) how to install iTunes on PlayOnLinux (start from step 4).